# Use elements of a list to iterate and use them as connection arguments

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm currently using psycopg2 to connect to my postgres db. I'm collecting the user credentials in a list, for example:

```
creds = ['username','password','host','port','db']
    
connection = psycopg2.connect(database=creds[0],user=creds[1],password=creds[2],host=creds[3],port=creds[4])
```

What I'm trying to achieve is having these values inserted them through an iteration, using lambdas or internal loops... I've seen them but haven't explored much into them.

My expected result is:

```
connection = pyscopg2.connect(connValues)
```

Or any other more "cleaner method" will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

---

If I try to store it as a string and use it, it gives me the following error:

```
 conVal = f'database={creds[0]},user={creds[1]},password={creds[2]},host={creds[3]},port={creds[4]}'

 connection = psycopg2.connect(conVal)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    connection = psycopg2.connect(conVal)
  File "C:\Users\edwin.romero\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edwin.romero\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extensions.py", line 153, in make_dsn
    parse_dsn(dsn)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "database"
```

---

I can see the error now. If I print the values of ConVal I get the following results:

```
conVal
'database=analytics,user=svc_talend_qa,password=Y8MKpKH6I3yl,host=pgsql-talend-qa-db01.cgd7p2bih6zs.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com,port=5432'
```

And this is taking 1 string as an argument instead of setting the correct arguments... looking into psycopg2 default values.

Comment: If I try to create a single string and use it, does not work...
```
 code
```

Comment: `dbname` not `database`.

Comment: Yes, used dbname and could connect using a single string,